# Cannot resolve method 'getSignInCredentialFromIntent' in 'GoogleSignInClient'

Tags: java, android, google-signin

As you can see, I have the correct dependencies included, the classes are included yet I still get this error. And I have been following the doc to the letter. I am not sure what is wrong and why

Declaration of Variables

```
private GoogleSignInClient oneTapClient;
private BeginSignInRequest signInRequest;
```

Initialization of variables

```
oneTapClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(getActivity(), gso);

        signInRequest = BeginSignInRequest.builder()
                .setGoogleIdTokenRequestOptions(BeginSignInRequest.GoogleIdTokenRequestOptions.builder()
                        .setSupported(true)
                        .setServerClientId(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                        .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(true)
                        .build())
                .build();
```

ActivityResultLauncher

```
ActivityResultLauncher<IntentSenderRequest> activityResultLauncher =
                registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.StartIntentSenderForResult(), new ActivityResultCallback<ActivityResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResult(ActivityResult result) {
                        if (result.getResultCode() == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                            try {
                                SignInCredential credential = oneTapClient.
```

> getSignInCredentialFromIntent (issue = Cannot resolve method 'getSignInCredentialFromIntent' in 'GoogleSignInClient')

```
(result.getData());
                                    String idToken = credential.getGoogleIdToken();
                                    if (idToken !=  null) {
                                        String email = credential.getId();
                                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Email: " + email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                } catch (ApiException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Google Sign In btn - on click listener

```
googleSignInBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                oneTapClient.
```

> beginSignIn (issue = Cannot resolve method 'beginSignIn' in 'GoogleSignInClient')

```
(signInRequest)
                            .addOnSuccessListener(getActivity(), new OnSuccessListener<BeginSignInResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(BeginSignInResult result) {
                                        IntentSenderRequest intentSenderRequest =
                                                new IntentSenderRequest.Builder(result.getPendingIntent().getIntentSender()).build();
                                        activityResultLauncher.launch(intentSenderRequest);
                                }
                            })
                            .addOnFailureListener(getActivity(), new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    // No Google Accounts found. Just continue presenting the signed-out UI.
                                    Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
                                }
                            });
                }
            });
```

Dependencies

dependencies {

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.7.0'
implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0')
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:22.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:24.10.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
```

}